# How run Docker's container with IIS in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, iis, docker

Excuse me for my bad english.

My problem: Docker's IIS container don't install in Ubuntu... I have error's when i try pull this containers.

[image: Pull's errors]

Docker's Hub Pages : https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/ и https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis/ ...

Container microsoft/dotnet normal working in Ubuntu. What i need do that will install and start container with IIS in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Windows containers don't run on Linux hosts. You'll need windows server.

See this [github issue](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/1917) for more info

Comment: Container "microsoft/dotnet" normal working https://www.evernote.com/l/ADyb8gj6HbZP7pTtsk0tR4QQEsznuSFmAdw . On page https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis/ : "Install docker on your OS (Ubuntu, Debian, Windows 10, Windows Server 2016, Nano Server, etc.). Once docker is installed, execute in elevated prompt (bash, powershell 5, etc): docker pull nanoserver/iis"

Comment: Maybe there is some variant?