# How to run mvc 5 web app as a Docker container in Linux 16.04.5?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, docker-container

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**

- I have created a **mvc 5** web application in Visual Studio 2015, using `c#` on Windows 10 as a host machine's operating system
- The target framework version of build is: **4.5.2**

---

**WHAT I WANT:**

- I have an Ubuntu 16.04.5 installed on a VMware's machine
- The virtual-machine mentioned above has Docker installed/setup to manage/create containers
- Coming to my point, what I want is to containerize the web application using Docker
- I want the web application to run on a Docker container

Comment: what's your OS of host?

Comment: Windows 10 is the host OS @TonyY

Comment: why don't you directly install docker of windows version?

Comment: I have other containers of **m-cord** (architecture built from openstack and xos-services) to deal with in the future. All other containers are in linux. Any suggestions in this aspect would be helpful! @TonyY

Comment: Is [aspnet core](https://www.asp.net/core/overview/aspnet-vnext) not an option? Both dotnet core and aspnet core run on linux containers.

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Further pro-tips: please do not use HTML to format questions here - use Markdown instead. Also, please refrain from adding code formatting to things that are not actually code - Docker and Visual Studio are just proper nouns, and do not need preformatting.

Answer (score 2):

Windows containers can't run on Linux hosts.
[the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248432/how-run-dockers-container-with-iis-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Winodws only as follows.

1.Pull the IIS Server container
https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/

2.Deploy your mvc 5 web application on it

Comment: I think this is for Windows host. But i want the application to be run under linux-docker-container! Is there a way Mr. @TonyY

Comment: bad news :< @MalikAsif

Comment: is there any tool that builds the web application in host machine as a linux build and then deploy that build over linux. 
Or is there any way that i use visual-studio over linux and develop the application!
By the way, thank you very much. Your answer is helpful for the community!

Comment: Build .NET 4.5 Applications in a Linux Environment using Mono and XBuild. https://medium.com/@hudsonmendes/build-net-4-5-on-linux-in-5-minutes-and-see-what-it-is-like-848ea45fc667